# Can one purchase the title of "Lord", "Laird" or "Lady" in Scotland?

Tags: scam, scotland

I have recently started receiving Youtube advertisements for "Established titles", claiming to sell you a square foot of land in Scotland, entitling you to call yourself some variant of "Lord".

[Their website](https://establishedtitles.com) states:

> Our Title Packs are based on a historic Scottish land ownership custom, where landowners have been long referred to as "Lairds", the Scottish term for "Lord", with the female equivalent being "Lady".

It seems that they [have a competitor](https://www.highlandtitles.com/) or [two](https://scottishlaird.co.uk) offering a similar deal.

Is there any truth to this claim? Can any land owner, let alone someone whose holdings are worth around $50, in Scotland indeed style himself "Laird"?

Comment: The website itself was only created "Creation Date: 2019-12-09T04:47:59Z" - [centralops](https://centralops.net/co/), first sampled by [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200801000000*/establishedtitles.com) on 24th April 2020. The individual website may or may not be legitimate - do you have an alternative source of a similar offer? I'm not sure we can answer regarding a single website's scammy nature or not, I'll let others chime in.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. That was the website that the Youtube ad linked to. I have added a link to a competitor's website.

Comment: Also, I think separate questions for the validity of the charities behind these three offers might be warranted.

Comment: Just for interest. It seems to be a nest of almost identical websites: [esteemed titles](https://www.esteemedtitles.com/pages/about-us) and [historic titles](https://historictitles.com/pages/about-us) can be tied to the OP's first example as having cloned text content. From experience, this is usually a clue to something not quite above board going-on. I've not looked into the others in the OP's post.

Comment: As your own [link](https://www.highlandtitles.com/) says: "These are souvenir plots of land ... you are not officially a landowner ... not legally viewed as [Lord]." So you are not "entitled".

Comment: There is a related scam whereby housing sized plots are sold in places where planning permission isn't remotely likely, and the land is frequently peat bog, too deep for building. And another not-so-much scam, more like amusing gift, where the square foot of land entitles the holder to the occasional free dram at the nearby distillery. https://thewhiskeywash.com/whiskey-styles/scotch-whiskey/heres-how-you-can-have-your-own-tiny-plot-of-islay-hint-it-involves-whisky/

Comment: I suspect you can and may call yourself what you like in Scotland (apart from claiming a regulated professional qualification).
I suspect even more strongly that your home country won't have a law against claiming a Scottish title.
But the only people who get actual (hereditary) rights from UK titles are members of the House of Lords who have been elected by the others as voting peers.

Comment: I'm Lord pipe. I can call myself whatever I want. I wonder what the actual claim is here, are you asking about any _legal_ ramifications?

Comment: @HAEM The 'scottishlaird' site is registered as [Dunans Castle, Ltd.](https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/SC372423) and 'highlandtitles' is registered as [charity CH444](http://www.guernseyregistry.com/CharitiesRegister). If you're curious about the groups behind these sites, then that's probably the best place to start. Someone who lives in the UK would be better suited than I am at advising how to locate more specific details.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The Court of the Lord Lyon, the official authority on these things, [states on the matter](https://www.courtofthelordlyon.scot/coats%20of%20arms.htm) (bolding mine):

> A dwelling house of whatever size presents no problem, but the ownership of forestry land or “amenity” land on which there is no house and for which planning permission for a house would not be obtainable would not necessarily be sufficient to bring the owner into the Lord Lyon’s jurisdiction. ***The ownership of “souvenir” plots of land of a few square feet or thereby such as are marketed from time to time, is insufficient to bring anyone within the jurisdiction of the Lord Lyon King of Arms.***

So, just getting a coat of arms, let alone the title of Laird, requires ownership of a substantial amount of land. Therefore, the claim is false.

Comment: I can't say I'm surprised at this. Nice one, welcome to skeptics.

Comment: So it appears that the answer to the question is in fact "yes, but you have to buy more than this."

Comment: I'm not sure that buying more land would _guarantee_ anything; rather, they have had to provide special guidance about these tiny "souvenir" plots in particular, because they've become such a problem. So all that's guaranteed is that buying one of these plots does _not_ get you anything.

Comment: The Court of the Lord Lyon (both from its own web page and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Court_of_the_Lord_Lyon ) is Scotland's Heraldic Authority, i.e. registers the right to register a coat of arms. That it is not the same as the ability to style oneself "Lord", "Laird" or "Lady". Wikipedia is a poor source (hence this is not an answer), but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barons_in_Scotland implies being recognised by the Lord Lyon is a necessary but not sufficient condition.

Comment: "the jurisdiction of the Lord Lyon King of Arms" doesn't mean "being called Laird".

Comment: @GlennWillen - Aren't you overlooking the part of the quote where they say "A dwelling house of whatever size presents no problem"?  I'm assuming that they mean that purchasing a dwelling house with the land on which it is built would guarantee *something*.

Comment: You can "style" yourself anything you like, with or without land. Also the claim made on these websites is quite clear that "Please note—you may choose to style yourself as a Laird, Lord or Lady, but please remember that under Scottish Law, this is a title only and you have no legal rights or obligations attached to the parcel of land."

Answer (score 26):

[The Law Society of Scotland would like to clarify](https://www.lawscot.org.uk/members/journal/issues/vol-57-issue-04/caution-the-souvenir-hunters/) that this doesn't even really include proper title to the land, let alone the chivalric title.

> The Keeper is required to reject an application for registration in the Land Register, if the land to which it relates meets the description of “souvenir plot”. However, the fact that the Keeper is obliged to reject registration does not necessarily mean that “ownership” can be obtained by some other means.

> A real right of ownership in land (in the sense of a right that is enforceable against third parties) can only be obtained by registration in the Land Register or by recording a deed in the Register of Sasines as appropriate.

The standard public source for peerage information is [Burke's Peerage.](https://www.burkespeerage.com/preview.php?book=Preview%20of%20Burke%E2%80%99s%20Landed%20Gentry%20Scotland&ref=pScotland&page=1&totalPages=10&from=subs_ind)

Realistically, you can obtain a real peerage by a substantial donation to the ruling party, [Labour](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2015/mar/21/revealed-link-life-peerages-party-donations) or [Conservative](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2021/jun/12/boris-johnson-faces-legal-action-over-peerage-for-billionaire-tory-donor-peter-cruddas). This is technically illegal, but in practice nobody has been successfully prosecuted for it recently. The cost of this is about that of a small flat in London.

Comment: The linked articles contain approximate numbers: "average of a further £220,000 among Conservatives, £333,000 among Liberal Democrats and £464,000 among Labour nominees." - but the number for a transaction that both parties deny is a transaction can never be precise.

Comment: Oh, fair enough, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can style yourself as "Laird", but you won't have a title in the sense that you're thinking about.

The fine print on the [highlandtitles.com](https://www.highlandtitles.com/) website describes it well:

> You obtain a personal right to a souvenir plot of land and
> our *permission to use our registered trademarks, Laird,
> Lord and Lady of Glencoe*

> You obtain a personal right to a souvenir plot of land. This
> is a form of heritable property that you can pass on to
> future generations. Highland Titles remains as the registered
> landowner and manages the land on your behalf.

> You will be addressed by your choice of Laird, Lord or Lady
> *by us and within our 200,000+ strong community*. Please note
> you cannot buy a noble title. This is for enjoyment
> purposes only.

(emphasis mine)

What you're buying is a "personal right to a souvenir plot of land". This right is permanent and can be inherited by your heirs.  Actual land ownership is retained by the Highland Titles Charitable Trust for Scotland, who sells these plots as a fundraiser for their conservation programs (the plot itself is inside a nature reserve).

The group selling the titles has registered a trademark for the "Laird/Lord/Lady of Glencoe".  By purchasing a souvenir plot, they're also giving you a license to use their trademarks.  In addition, they'll call you by that name when communicating with you, and other donors/titleholders like to do so as well.  That's not the same thing as a *real* title, though.  I doubt anyone else will call you by that title, and there are thousands of other people that also use the same title.  The [scottishlaird.co.uk](http://scottishlaird.co.uk) website calls them "decorative titles", which is an apt description.

I'm not sure I agree with the 'scam' tag as these don't seem to be intentionally deceptive, although I see where it could be confusing for those who live outside the UK and are unfamiliar with how titles work.  It's just a fun little way of rewarding those who donate to their conservation/restoration efforts.

Comment: Whilst most of what you write makes perfect sense, I'm unable to find any connection to the conservation effort cited on the website, there is a community initiative, but there doesn't seem to be a way of donating funds to it, and since the company is based in New York US, it seems improbable they contribute their manpower to the effort.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I'm not sure what you mean by "based in New York US".  The three sites I linked to all show addresses in the UK. Some of them may have *websites* that are hosted and managed by a third party located elsewhere, though.  All three will let you visit the project they're supposedly maintaining so you can personally verify that your money is going towards the conservation project if you really wanted to.

Comment: If you examine the terms and conditions on the wayback machine dated the [6th of May 2020](https://establishedtitles.com/), they state " The laws of the State of New York shall govern these Terms and Conditions." same as the modern version - perhaps I'm misreading the situation. Cont...

Comment: They also say in their privacy section "Under California Law, California residents have the right to request in writing from businesses with whom they have an established business relationship..." - but say nothing regarding EU privacy laws. Perhaps they're just aimed at the US market, or not. The clones I mention in the comments do seem to have been created after this site - the implication being that this is the original. The address cited on the clones (Lessendrum, Huntly, AB54 6XR) is identical to that on the original, cont...

Comment: maybe they were looking to corner the market, or maybe they were expecting to get one or more sites closed because of legal challenges(??). There's more to know about this company than is on obvious display, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: Also, I couldn't find a link to the conservation initiative, couldn't find their website with an independent search - is there a link to a veritably legitimate site re conservation in Scotland as they state where doners are listed?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Those T&Cs and Privacy Policy are only for the *website*, which is most likely managed by a third party service provider. Several of those sites list charity registration numbers on their site if you want to look them up. They also show [maps](https://establishedtitles.com/pages/proof-of-land-ownership-in-scotland) detailing where their land is, if you want to check against property records. Your best bet is probably to click the "Contact Us" button and ask them directly.

Comment: Could you give a URL which points to a charity number on the site listed in the question because I can't find one? Checking property records takes time and money, anyone can have a map on their site - asking them directly is somewhat beside the point. We don't make assumptions on skeptics so-much, we provide verifiable evidence where possible and generally try to be as rigorous as we can.

Comment: This question merely asks whether a title can be purchased. The activities and legitimacy of individual websites/organizations is off-topic. You can ask a new question if you'd like, the comment section is not the appropriate place to provide detailed answers to questions.

Comment: Might I suggest that you omit the last sentence of your answer as it appears to not be justified by any evidence you can produce.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128178/discussion-between-bta-and-a-rogue-ant).

Comment: Oooh, how interesting. By the exact same reasoning and legal processes, I could declare tomorrow that I am forming the Galactic Senate and sell people titles of "senator for Altair" and "senator for Rigel" and whatever, and that *I* will address you as "senator" and other members of my club will address you as "senator". And that would be all it means. I don't know any reason why that wouldn't be completely legal. And pretty worthless beyond being an amusing little game.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, these purchases do allow you to use the title of "Laird" or "Lord". Please see the official government guidance on [titles for passports](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/959788/Titles_V7.pdf) (.pdf link), which states (p. 13/14):

> Bought and styled titles
>
> **Bought titles may be sold by internet companies**.
>
> ...
>
> In the past, holders of bought or styled titles had to write to the Manorial Society of Great Britain for confirmation of the right to use and be known by a title. This society is a private company, in direct competition with many others that deal in the buying and selling of titles.
>
> You must never tell a customer to contact the Manorial Society of Great Britain for confirmation, unless they have bought the title from the society.
>
> You must only add an observation for customers with bought or styled titles, if it’s
> included in this guidance (for example, a manorial title)

(My emphasis, some text omited). Which clearly states that the passport office will include a title such as these *on your passport*, what more official record could there be? But wait, what was the bit I omitted:

> Styled titles mean self-styled or presumed titles that customers have created for
> themselves.

Huh. So you could just make up a title for yourself and use that? Yup, you don't actually need to buy the package to call yourself a Lord, you can just do it. This is unsurprising because in the UK, unlike in some countries, your name is simply what you call yourself and you are free to change it to almost anything on a whim: although something like a [deed poll](https://www.gov.uk/change-name-deed-poll) is useful to prove that you are going by the new name for formal purposes.

In fact, this applies to all titles in the UK. It even extends to titles like "Dr", unless you're using them to fraudulently misrepresent yourself or mislead the public, as in the famous case of [Gilian McKeith](https://www.theguardian.com/media/2007/feb/12/broadcasting.food).

Of course, calling yourself a Lord doesn't give you any privileges or authority, and you will get short shrift in high society if you tried to use such an internet title. Real and meaningful Lordships are tracked and validated by [The Court of the Lord Lyon in Scotland](https://www.courtofthelordlyon.scot/) which is also the body responsible for Coats of Arms in Scotland.

Comment: I think the "Yes" is a bit too resounding here, since the answer demonstrates that the purchase is ultimately unnecessary. I would advise revising the introduction of this answer to be clearer from the get go that there's no need to buy anything.

Comment: Isn't "Lord Buckethead" more of just a chosen name than a title?  He's no more an actual Lord than Queen Latifah or Prince are actual royalty.  (And unlike them, he's not even one person, but several people at different times.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Sure, using a title doesn't make it have any meaning. Just as becoming Laird by "buying" a square foot of land in Scotland doesn't.

Comment: Lord Buckethead is explicitly a character, played by multiple people at different times, but [Screaming Lord Sutch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screaming_Lord_Sutch) was an individual, who added "Lord" to his name by deed poll (a deed poll just being a declaration that you wish to be known exclusively by the new name, with no requirement to register with any official body; the UK is really bad at tracking identity).

Comment: @MatthieuM. If the question was "what do you need to do to style yourself Laird in Scotland", I'd agree.

Comment: When registering as a candidate in a UK election, a person has to provide two names - a legal name and a "known-as" name (they obviously can be the same).  This is to allow Samantha Smith to appear on the ballot paper as Sam Smith as everyone  knows her as.  This rule has the effect of allowing people to register as "Lord Buckethead" without having to change their name by a legal means.  It is entirely up to the Presiding Officer (usually effected by the Elections Manager) to allow the name.  Therefore election names have nothing to do with the purchase of titles.

Comment: @JonathanTwite: Thanks for the correction, I will edit.

Comment: Lord Buckethead, ironically, stands in elections to the House of ... Commons.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman given the person with the title 'Lord Loftus' has been "several people at different times" (nine in fact) so that in itself hardly invalidates the use of a title. If they went by 'John, the seventh Lord Buckethead' then there being more than one of them might be unusual, just as there's only one 'Charles, 1st Lord Loftus", but a title usually can have multiple different holders at different times.

Comment: @PeteKirkham and in this case multiple holders at the *same* time. There is more than one souvenir plot for sale.

Comment: @user_1818839 He also ran for PM against Thatcher.  But my understanding is the House of Lords is not elected, right?  So he couldn't run for that if he wanted to.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Indeed, not only is the House of Lords unelected, but famously (and logically), a Lord cannot become a member of the Commons. Tony Benn renounced his title, became an MP (in the Commons) and the Tories would wind him up by referring to "the former Viscount Stansgate"! So Lord Buckethead could only run against Mrs T (for the Commons) because he isn't a Lord.

Comment: @user_1818839: The rules about Lords in the commons was revoked at the same time most Lords were removed from the House of Lords. Now it's only if you're a Lord in the House of Lords that you can't also be in the House of Commons.